# lookup and sum values associated with different IDs

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, lookup, data-manipulation

I have a file that includes the a value for **depression** associated with each unique value for **ID**. The data frame called **HAVE** looks like this:

```
id  depression friendid_A friendid_B friendid_C friendid_D
1          1.0         NA          3          6          5
2          0.6          6          4         NA         NA
3          0.0          1          4          5         NA
4          1.8          1          3         NA          2
5          1.7         NA         NA         NA         NA
6          0.3          2          3         NA         NA
```

I want to add a variable **depression_sum** that looks up the value of **depression** for each ID listed in an observation, and adds them up. For example, the first observation includes IDs 3, 6, and 5 for its various **friendid_n** variables. Values of **depression** for these three IDs are 0.0, 0.3, and 1.7, respectively. The **depression_sum** for this observation would thus be 2.0.

Below is the data frame called **WANT** that I would like to create:

```
id  depression  friendid_A  friendid_B  friendid_C  friendid_D  depression_sum
1          1.0          NA           3           6           5            2.0
2          0.6           6           4          NA          NA            2.1
3          0.0           1           4           5          NA            4.5
4          1.8           1           3          NA           2            1.6
5          1.7          NA          NA          NA          NA             NA
6          0.3           2           3          NA          NA            0.6
```

Is there a way to effectively look up these values and create a variable that includes their sum?

Comment: You might like to rename columns to `friendid_a, _b, _c, _d` to avoid confusion

Comment: just did - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tidyverse` solution

```
library(tidyverse)

WANT <- HAVE %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id, -depression, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(
    depression_sum = sum(HAVE$depression[match(value, HAVE$id)])
  ) %>%
  left_join(HAVE, .)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HAVE <- read.table(text="id  depression friendid_1 friendid_2 friendid_3 friendid_4
1          1.0         NA          3          6          5
2          0.6          6          4         NA         NA
3          0.0          1          4          5         NA
4          1.8          1          3         NA          2
5          1.7         NA         NA         NA         NA
6          0.3          2          3         NA         NA", header=T, sep='', row.names='id')

friends <- HAVE[, 2:ncol(HAVE)]
```

Then there are two ways to go:

- sweep a match function row-wise which looks for matches of 1,2,3... in each row. (It might be easier to first expand `friends` into an adjacency matrix)
- use `merge()` (SQL join) on 'id' as per @MelissaKey's suggestion. You can do this in base without tidyverse, but it's a bit painful.

Answer (score 1):

One can modify `HAVE` data.frame itself by adding a column to it. Perhaps, need to create another data.frame `WANT`(as specified by `OP`) can be avoided.

A solution in `base-R` using `apply`:

```
HAVE$depression_sum <- apply(df[3:nrow(df)], 1,
            function(x)sum(df$depression[HAVE$id %in% x], na.rm = TRUE))

HAVE
#   id depression friendid_A friendid_B friendid_C friendid_D depression_sum
# 1  1        1.0         NA          3          6          5            2.0
# 2  2        0.6          6          4         NA         NA            2.1
# 3  3        0.0          1          4          5         NA            4.5
# 4  4        1.8          1          3         NA          2            1.6
# 5  5        1.7         NA         NA         NA         NA            0.0
# 6  6        0.3          2          3         NA         NA            0.6
```